# Why do I get a naming convention error in PySpark when the name is correct?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, naming-conventions, aggregation

I'm trying to groupBy a variable (column) called `saleId`, and then get the Sum for it, using an attribute (column) called `totalAmount` with the code below:

```
df = df.groupBy('saleId').agg({"totalAmount": "sum"})
```

But I get the following error:

> Attribute sum(totalAmount) contains an invalid character among
> ,;{}()\n\t=. Please use an alias to rename it

I'm assuming there's something wrong with the way I'm using groupBy, because I get other errors even when I try the following code instead of the above one:

```
df = df.groupBy('saleId').sum('totalAmount')
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: @过过招 version is 3.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured out what went wrong.

The code I used in my question, returns the whole `sum(totalAmount)` as the name of the variable (column), which as you can see includes parenthesis.

This can be avoided by using:

```
df= df.groupBy('saleId').agg({"totalAmount": "sum"}).withColumnRenamed('sum(totalAmount)', 'totalAmount')
```

or

```
df.groupBy('saleId').agg(F.sum("totalAmount").alias(totalAmount))
```

Comment: I don't think so this was the problem because this code is working for me :

>>> df.groupBy('sale_id').agg({"amount": "sum"}).show()
+------------+-----------+
|     sale_id|sum(amount)|
+------------+-----------+
|189012240044|    2185613|
|193012020044|      62715|
+------------+-----------+

Comment: @SachinTiwari So, possibly this is the version issue! Or perhaps the platform and setup(?)

Comment: you have spaces somewhere in column name Total amount

Comment: @SachinTiwari !!! No, I do not! :)